# React-leaflet bounds

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Right now I am setting the bounds of my react leaflet map by passing a bounds parameter as shown below:

```
   <div hidden={!this.props.hide && !this.props.toggle} className="map-container">

       <Leaflet.Map ref='leaflet-map' bounds={ this.getBounds()} >

       <Leaflet.TileLayer url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'/>

             { this.geoResults().map(this.renderMarker) }


       </Leaflet.Map>

   </div>
```

The problem is that sometimes a marker is rendered on the outermost part of the map (in view) so the marker is not even visible unless I drag the map or zoom out one spot. I was trying to fix this with a buffer or trying to plot the bounds then use zoom to zoom out once but nothing seems to work. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: This might also help if other people are coming here, like I did, looking for a fuller solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601692/fit-map-to-feature-layer-bounds-in-react-leaflet/53609537#53609537

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution**

You can use `boundsOptions` attribute of the `Map` component to pass options to the leaflet's `fitBounds()` method. In those options you can define `padding` for example to "pad" the bounds.

From `react-leaflet` [Map](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#mapcontainer) documentation:

> boundsOptions: object (optional): Options passed to the fitBounds() method.

From `leaflet` [fitBounds options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-fitbounds) documentation:

> padding: Equivalent of setting both top left and bottom right padding to the same value.

**Example**

So something like this should work (didn't test in action):

```
<Leaflet.Map
  ref='leaflet-map'
  bounds={this.getBounds()}
  boundsOptions={{padding: [50, 50]}}
/>
```

Defining your Map element like that should pad the bounds. Tune the padding values to suite your needs.

**Another approach**

You could add padding to the bounds in your `getBounds()` function.

Comment: Awesome answer - I have gotten to this part and now I want to add vector polygon on top of the bounds of the map so they can see the exact polygon I am providing in the bounds argument.  Can you take a look at my question over here and see if you know the answer to it as well? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234377/leaflet-js-react-leaflet-bounds-box-filled-with-transparent-color

Comment: Thanks maxwell. I did make a suggestion for your other problem too. Could you mark my answer as correct and consider upvoting it (that is kinda the idea of gamification of StackOverlow after all). Cheers.