# Leaflet JS (react-leaflet) - Bounds Box Filled With Transparent Color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working with react-leaflet package, however, if you can answer the question in plain leaflet that would be helpful as well.

I am successfully panning to the bounds of a polygon that I supply like so:

```
<Map center={position}
                 zoom={13}
                 bounds={this.state.bounds}
                 className="campaignimagery-map">
                 <TileLayer
                    url="http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution=""
                 />
```

However, I would like the entire polygon boundary box to be some transparent color so they can see exactly where the boundary box lies on the map.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you mean adding some lines that represent your rectangle boundary bounds?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Use the bounds to draw a colored rectangle like this `L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);`. See related [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle) for more information.

**Explanation**

I don't think it's possible to color bounds as is, but you can use bounds for drawing a polygon. Then the polygon itself can be colored and managed as you wish.