# Fit map to feature layer bounds in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

## What I want to achieve:

Have a `<Map><FeatureGroup><Circle />[1 or more]...</FeatureGroup></Map>` hierarchy and fit the map bounds to the feature group so that all the circles are in the viewport.

If there is only one circle, it should fit the bounds (ie: zoom in on) to that circle.

## What I've tried:

1. giving `FeatureGroup` a `ref` and calling `getBounds` on it to pass onto `Map`. Because of the lifecycle `FeatureGroup` doesn't exist at the time `componentDidMount` is called - it gets rendered later (https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/106#issuecomment-161594328).
2. Storing `Circle` in state and calling getBounds on that (assuming, in this case, that there is only one circle. That didn't work either.

I think I might need to do something with the React Context but I'm not sure that I fully understand it right now, so I need some help.

## Other information

I'm using `react-leaflet@2.1.2`

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the contents of the `Map` are unavailable at `componentDidMount`-time (https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/106#issuecomment-161594328) you cannot get the bounds of the `FeatureGroup` at that point, and out of all the  `refs` you assign, only the `Map` ref will be available in `this.refs`.

However, as per this GitHub comment: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/106#issuecomment-366263225 you can give a `FeatureGroup` an `onAdd` handler function:

```
<FeatureGroup ref="features" onAdd={this.onFeatureGroupAdd}>...
```

and you can then use the `Map` refs to access the `leafletElement` and call `fitBounds` with the bounds of the incoming event target, which will be the `FeatureGroup`:

```
  onFeatureGroupAdd = (e) => {
    this.refs.map.leafletElement.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }
```

This will then "zoom" the map into the bounds of your `FeatureGroup`, as desired.

### Update

I modified my React component so that zoom and centre are controlled by query parameters. The problem with the above solution was that if you zoomed in on a `MarkerClusterGroup` by clicking on it, for example, it would update the zoom in the url, re-render the map and re-call `onFeatureGroupAdd`, thus undoing all the marker cluster goodness.

What I needed was to access the zoom level required to keep the newly drawn circle nicely in bounds, then update the url with the correct zoom level and center.

```
  onDrawCircle = (e) => {
    ...
    var targetZoom = this.refs.map.leafletElement.getBoundsZoom(e.layer.getBounds());
        // Call function to update url here:
        functionToUpdateUrl(targetZoom, e.layer.getBounds().getCenter());
    }
  }
```

In order to be able to control the whole map I also call `functionToUpdateUrl` in `onZoomEnd` and `onDragEnd` event handlers, like so:

```
  onChangeView = (e) => {
      functionToUpdateUrl(e.target._zoom, this.refs.map.leafletElement.getCenter());
  }
```

and one for handling cluster clicks:

```
  onClusterClick = (e) => {
     // This time we want the center of the layer, not the map?
     functionToUpdateUrl(e.target._zoom, (e.layer ? e.layer.getBounds().getCenter() : e.target.getBounds().getCenter()));
  }
```

Then, when rendering the Map element, pass these properties:

```
  <Map
    center={center}
    ref='map'
    zoom={zoom}
    maxZoom={18}
    onZoomEnd={this.onChangeView}
    onDragEnd={this.onChangeView}
  >
  ....
  </Map>
```

And remember to give any `MarkerClusterGroup`s their `onClusterClick` callback:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup onAdd={this.onMarkerGroupAdd} onClusterClick={this.onClusterClick}>
```

Comment: I found I had to use `onadd` rather than `onAdd`, `<FeatureGroup onadd={onFeatureGroupAdd}>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `getBounds` in the `componentDidMount` function instead of `componentWillMount`? If that doesn't work then I'd suggest extending the `FeatureGroup` component and adding an `onLoaded` function as as prop and call that function in the `componentDidMount` function of your extended component. And by extending the `FeatureGroup` component I actually mean copying/pasting it from [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/FeatureGroup.js). (if you care about why you need to copy that whole file check [this](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506) thread)

This isn't tested but your code will probably look something like

```
import { FeatureGroup } from 'leaflet';

import { withLeaflet, Path } from 'react-leaflet';

class CustomFeatureGroup extends Path {
  createLeafletElement(prop) {
    const el = new FeatureGroup(this.getOptions(props));
    this.contextValue = {
      ...props.leaflet,
      layerContainer: el,
      popupContainer: el,
    };
    return el;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    this.setStyle(this.props);
    /*
     Here you can do your centering logic with an onLoad callback or just
     by using this.leafletElement.map or whatever
    */
    this.props.onLoaded();
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(CustomFeatureGroup)
```

Note: If you are using `react-leaflet` V1 this is actually way easier and I can edit this answer with that code if needed.

Comment: Ah, it turns out I was doing it in componentDidMount. Someone has obviously managed to get access to the Circle via refs without extending any components (https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/34), which I'm also reluctant to do as I'm unsure what the impact will be maintenance-wise, but I can't work out how to do it. I'm using v2.1.2. If I cant figure out anything else then I'll give this a go, but it seems odd that it isn't possible without having to do this.