# Fit a map's bounds to contents of a FeatureGroup in React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a `FeatureGroup` with a `Circle` inside of it. On load, I want the map's viewport to completely show the circle. There are a number of relevant StackOverflow questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53601692/1749551), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50861984/1749551), [a third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743305/1749551)), and I have tried them all. None have worked for me using modern tools.

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, FeatureGroup, Circle } from 'react-leaflet'

export default function MyMap({volunteer, pollingPlaces}) {

    const coordinates = [40.781753, -73.966583];
    const circle = <Circle pathOptions={{color: 'purple'}} center={coordinates} radius={3*1609} />

    return (
        <MapContainer center={coordinates}
            style={{
                height:"400px",
                width: "400px"
            }}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <FeatureGroup>
                {circle}
            </FeatureGroup>
        </MapContainer>
        )
}
```

One of the big problems is that [string refs are now deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs), and most of the old answers rely on this. It's also not clear to me how to use the new [`useMap`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap) hook in concert with the [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) method *in a function component*. (The [third approach above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743305/1749551) seems to get the closest, and is from just a year ago, but it still relies on `componentDidMount`.) Finally, I am unable to get my FeatureGroup to call either the `onadd` or [`onAdd`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer-onadd) method (it's unclear [which is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609537/1749551)? see comment below the answer…) when I pass it to the component. The 2018 answer relies on this callback.

The combination of these three issues mean I can't get any of the old solutions working. So I thought I'd ask anew: what's the right way to do this these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the question described in the title, as you have another one later regarding `onAdd` and it is better to ask it separately in my opinion, you can still use a [ref](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#featuregroup) to get a reference to the `FeatureGroup`

All you need is to call `map.fitBounds`. To get the map reference you need to use `whenCreated` prop inside the component that includes `MapContainer`. If you were inside a child you would have to use `useMap` hook to get it. Once you get this you need to use the `featureGroup` ref which is a react ref, an object actually, and can be accessed via `current`. Inside there you have some leaflet methods. The one you need is `getBounds` method to retrieve the bounds of your feature group.

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const featureGroupRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    map.fitBounds(featureGroupRef.current.getBounds());
  }, [map]);

 <MapContainer
      center={coordinates}
      zoom={6}
      style={{
        height: "400px",
        width: "400px"
      }}
      whenCreated={setMap}
 >
  ...

 <FeatureGroup ref={featureGroupRef}>{circle}</FeatureGroup>
</MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fit-a-maps-bounds-to-contents-of-a-featuregroup-in-react-leaflet-v3-y81d7?file=/src/Map.jsx:608-769)

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This worked right away. For posterity: `createRef` is the class component equivalent of `useRef`, so no surprise that my attempts to employ that in my function component were failing.