# Nextjs 14, Leaflet-react, setting map bounds on dynamic content load

Tags: next.js, leaflet

I am trying to use a leaflet map's `setBounds` around some GeoJSON tracks. The data is loaded at runtime.

Looking at [Fit a map's bounds to contents of a FeatureGroup in React-Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629532/fit-a-maps-bounds-to-contents-of-a-featuregroup-in-react-leaflet), I see that on map creation, a state variable is used to pass around the map object.  It looks like in the current version of leaflet-react, the same effect can be achieved using `useMap()` within a compnent that is a child of a `MapContainer`.

I have used the same `ref` that the link above referenced.

This works if the page soft reloads, as if I change the code and the client window refreshes.  If I force reload the browser page, the bounding doesn't happen, because `featureGroupRef.current` is not set (yet).

As a work-around, from [How do you call fitBounds() when using leaflet-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861984/how-do-you-call-fitbounds-when-using-leaflet-react), I've tried capturing the `layeradd` event from Leaflet, but it doesn't seem to be firing - or I'm not cathing the right event name. I know events are firing - I can catch the 'click' event, which leads me to believe that I am handling events in current leaflet-react correctly.

Code as below:

```js
const GeoJSON = dynamic(() => import('react-leaflet/GeoJSON'), {
  ssr: false,
});

const DEFAULT_CENTER = [47.000, -72.000]

export default function Home() {
  const featureGroupRef = useRef();

  function MyComponent() {
    console.log("Into MyComponent")
    const map = useMap()
    if (!map) return;
    console.log(".. we have a map ..")
    if (featureGroupRef.current === undefined) return;
    console.log(".. we have a featureGroupRef too ..")

    console.log("FeatureGroupRef: ", featureGroupRef);
    map.fitBounds(featureGroupRef.current.getBounds());

    return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Map className="mapcomponent" width="800" height="600" center={DEFAULT_CENTER} zoom={8} eventHandlers={{
        onlayeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
        layeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
        click: () => { console.log("geojson click") }
      }}>
        {({ TileLayer, GeoJSON, FeatureGroup }) => (
          <>
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            />
            <FeatureGroup ref={featureGroupRef} eventHandlers={{
              onlayeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
              layeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
              click: () => { console.log("geojson click") }
            }}>
              {Tracks.map((track, index) => (
                <GeoJSON key={index} data={track} eventHandlers={{
                  onlayeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
                  layeradd: () => { console.log('group changed') },
                  click: () => { console.log("geojson click") }
                }} />
              ))}
            </FeatureGroup>
            <MyComponent />
          </>
        )}
      </Map >
      <p>Hello.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Github is at https://github.com/timatlee/nextjs-leaflet/tree/main

Any direction or help is appreciated.